# How do I extract specific data from a .txt file in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have some text file which have data in the following format:

```
Summary:
xyz

Configuration:
abc
123

Tools:
pqr
456
```

The tags 'Summary:', 'Configuration:' and 'Tools:' remain the same for all the files and just the content below that changes. I need to extract just the content from the text file and print it out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
open(FH, '<myfile.txt');
while(<FH>)
{
  print $_ unless /Summary:|Configuration:|Tools:/;
}
```

You'll have to cleanup the regex a bit, but that should do it.

Comment: Thank you. As you said needed a bit of cleanup, but gave me the idea

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my (%h, $header);
while (<>) {
    if (/^(\w+):) { 
        $header = $1; 
    } elsif (defined $header) { 
        push @{$h{header}}, $_; }
}
print Dumper \%h;
```

If your non-header lines can contain `:`, you may need something stricter, such as:

```
if (/^(Summary|Configuration|Tools):/)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have one file or many, but if the former case:

```
Summary: xyz

Configuration: abc 123

Tools: pqr 456

Summary: xyzxyz

Configuration: abcd 1234

Tools: pqr 457
```

You can use something like the following to print all configuration lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

open (FILE, 'data.txt') or die "$!";

while (<FILE>) {
    if (m/^(Configuration):(.*)/) {
      print $2 . "\n";
    }
}
close FILE;
```

Change the regex if you want other lines or to `m/^(Configuration|Tools|Summary):(.*)/` for all of them.

Answer (score -1):

Or the considerably less elegant

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $fi;
my $line;
my @arr;
open($fi, "< tester.txt") or die "$!";

while ($line = <$fi>) 
{
    if (!($line =~ /:/))
    {
        push(@arr, $line);
    }
}

foreach (@arr)
{
    print $_;
}

close ($fi);
close ($fo);
```

Comment: please don't answer old posts with something considerably less elegant

Comment: Hmmm... I was thinking about how perl-golfed one liners are not always intuitive to newer Perl people. But meh I'm eternally a noob, or I would have noticed how old this is, heh.